# (Swift) How to show Cancel button on searchBar even if there is no text?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a searchBar with a `Cancel` button. Cancel button appears only when I start typing a text in searchBar. 
What I want is to show cancel button in the moment user taps the searchBar (when cursor and keyboard appears).

Code:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }
    var searching = false
```

searchBar methods:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let cancelButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGreen]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes , for: .normal)

        searching = true
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searching = false
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try delegate method

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

   searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

}
```

And

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
```